# Defense offense strategy basic

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am have to make this basic game engine.The offensive player has 5/6 chance to make a shot(83%).. And defense player has 4/6 chance(57.6%) to defend it.So when offensive player make a shot,how do I calculate the success rate of both players.Thank you for taking time to read this.I am starting new in this.Thanks in advance..

Comment: What does it mean to 'make a shot' and 'defend it' in a way that allows these probabilities to be consistent?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively it depends on how those things are related to another and how you formulate the question.
Let's first assume that the events are independent and the probability of a save is there (and the same!) even if the shot is missed (not realistic but it is a start).

If they are independent, that is if the chance of the offensive player to make a shot is not influenced by whether the defensive player makes his save (ie when the probabilities are always the same) - and vice versa, then it is rather simple.

The probability that the shot is made is $P(A)=0.83$ and that the save is made is $P(B)=0.576$

So the probability that a shot is made and that the save is missed is
$$P(A \cap \neg B) = P(A)*P(\neg B)$$
Where the $\cap$ denotes the "AND", while the $\neg B$ is the complement or opposite of B (so that a save is not made).
In values this is 
$$P(A \cap \neg B) =  P(A)*P(\neg B) = P(A)*(1-P(B)) = 0.83*(1-0.576) = 0.35192$$

So the probability that the shot is made and the save is not made is around 35%
For the defensive player it is similar, only that we need the event that the shot is made, and also that the save is made. This is:
$$P(A \cap B) =  P(A)*P(B)  = 0.83*0.576 = 0.4731$$

So 47,31%

However the problem with this is that this only works if the events are independent - if the probability of a miss is always 0.83 no matter if a save is made or not.

If this is not the case but if the probability 4/6 still describes the total chance of making a save even if the ball misses, the formula becomes a bit harder to calculate.
Let's say you want to know if the shot is made ($A$) but also the save is made ($B$).
Look at this picture I stole somewhere:
[image: Venn diagram]
If the events represent those circles, then the probability we are after is the intersection, right? Well if the events are not independent, then the formula is

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$$

Where $P(A \cup B)$ denotes the union of $A$ and $B$ (ie both circles together).
Why? Because when we add both circles together (or their probabilities), then we have the intersection we are after twice $P(A \cap B)$ but also the rest of the circles we don't need. This is what we subtract.

But what if a save only has the probability of 4/6 to be made if the shot is *not* missed, ie the realistic case?

You added the flag of conditional probability. This is another piece of information and it depends on what you mean in your post.
You can say that "the defensive player has a chance of 57.6% to defend a goal *if* the offensive player makes the shot (but not otherwise)"
Then this is the case where
$$P(B|A) = 0.576$$
The formula for this is then that
$$P(B|A) = 0.576 = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$$

The difference, once again imagining a Venn diagram as above, is that we are only looking at the chance to hit the intersection if we already hit in the circle A. So the probability of $P(B \cap A)$ is the intersection, but the *conditional* probability is the intersection as a percentage of the circle A.
This is a bit confusing but you can get it if you draw yourself some examples.

To solve this, you'd need more information about the probabilities of both events.